# change background of multiple text in JFace TextViewer

Tags: eclipse, jface

Is it possible to programatically change the background of multiple text in a TextViewer? For example, I have a word in my TextViewer document that is repeated several times. I would like to change the background colour of that.
I have tried adding LineBackgroundListener. But this changes the background of the whole line. I require only the chosen text to have a different background colour.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Create a `StyleRange` with the background you want and then apply it with `setStyleRanges(int[] ranges, StyleRange[] styles)` where `ranges` is a list of int-pairs (start and end of each range in the `styles` argument) and `styles` is an array with the length `ranges.length/2`. Just repeat the same style range N times.